# GraphQL schema for DynamoDB

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm using DynamoDB and want to create a database with GraphQL API.
How do I have to define my schema so my partition key is userID and my sort key is MMYY.
Every userID has a lot of MMYY, and every MMYY has entries which are just some data.

I want all of these entities to be in 1 table.

Is this the right way?

```
input AMPLIFY {
  globalAuthRule: AuthRule = { allow: public }
}

type UserID @model {
  userID: ID! # Assuming userID is the partition key
  mmYYEntries: [MMYY] @hasMany
}

type MMYY @model {
  userID: ID! # Assuming userID is the partition key
  MMYY: Int! # Assuming MMYY is the sort key and it's a whole number
  entries: [Entry] @hasMany
}

type Entry @model {
  dt: Int!
  bl: Int!
  bs: String!
  ss: Int!
}
```

Comment: Looks like it should require 3 tables as you have 2 @hasMany relationships. Also if `MMYY` is an `Int` then you'll have `123` for January 2023 instead of `0123`. You'd be better off with `YYMM` to sort correctly (at least until the year 2100)